# Div overflowing on navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to adjust responsiveness on my navbar but I started noticing when i get to sm/xs sizes the div with my nav items is overflowing

[image]

I'm basically just using the code straight out of the bootstrap website. However I have made the following changes. Could any of these be causing this?

Update: adding HTML aling with CSS

```css
.navbar{
    height: 10.0rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
}
.bg-light {
    background-color: white !important;
}
.navbar-collapse{
    padding-left: 0;
}
#navbarNav{
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60%;
}

#options li{
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.navbar-brand{
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#header-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* justify-content: space-evenly; */
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    height: 8rem;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Alan Alban</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <section id="header-container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="options">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Experience <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </nav>
```

I added a section container to see if it would extend the length of the screen but it still "shirnks" the nav when I make the screen smaller

Comment: You need to add html as well in your code snippet since the output isn't reproducing the issue

Comment: Add the html code also

Answer (score 0):

I hope you used flex for header container `#header-container`.

By default, `flex-wrap` would be `nowrap`. so change this default behaviour to `wrap`.